# I there a way of changing the text of "add child page" button wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Is there a way to change the text of the button **add child page** of default Page model of **Wagtail**?

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail provides a hooks system to override functionality throughout the admin interface. One of the hooks available is [construct_page_listing_buttons](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#construct-page-listing-buttons) which lets you customise the final list of buttons before it renders.

You will need to create a file in any app called `wagtail_hooks.py` which Wagtail will execute at the start. See - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#hooks

In the source you can see the [add page button generation](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/2.9.x/wagtail/admin/wagtail_hooks.py#L128) for reference on how they are added.

### Example code

**`wagtail_hooks.py`**

```
from wagtail.core import hooks
from wagtail.admin.widgets import Button, PageListingButton


@hooks.register('construct_page_listing_buttons') 
def replace_page_listing_button_item(buttons, page, page_perms, is_parent=False, context=None):
    for index, button in enumerate(buttons):
       # basic code only - recommend you find a more robust way to confirm this is the add child page button
        if button.label == 'Add child page':
            new_button = Button(...)
            buttons[index] = new_button # update the matched button with a new one (note. PageListingButton is used in page listing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor suggestion to avoid having to re-construct the button, since we are just replacing the text. Should also build this out so that it dynamically changes if the child pages are limited to a single content type.

##### **`wagtail_hooks.py`**

```
@hooks.register('construct_page_listing_buttons')
def replace_page_listing_button_item(buttons, page, page_perms, is_parent=False, context=None):
    for index, button in enumerate(buttons):
       # basic code only - recommend you find a more robust way to confirm this is the add child page button
        if button.label == 'Add child page':
            button.label = 'Add New...'
            buttons[index] = button # update the matched button with a new one (note. PageListingButton is used in page listing)
```